# Take unstructured df list in pandas and giving the data structure in two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I downloaded data from the web and stored it in a df.  I am new to python so some terms maybe incorrectly stated.

the df is below:

```
0   1   2   3
0   United States (105) United States (105) United States (105) United States (105)
1   NaN Alabama (0) Louisiana (2)   Ohio (4)
2   NaN Alaska (0)  Maine (0)   Oklahoma (0)
3   NaN Arizona (0) Maryland (2)    Oregon (0)
4   NaN Arkansas (0)    Massachusetts (9)   Pennsylvania (28)
5   NaN California (0)  Michigan (1)    Rhode Island (0)
6   NaN Colorado (0)    Minnesota (0)   South Carolina (0)
7   NaN Connecticut (3) Mississippi (0) South Dakota (0)
8   NaN Delaware (1)    Missouri (1)    Tennessee (0)
9   NaN Florida (0) Montana (0) Texas (0)
10  NaN Georgia (0) Nebraska (0)    Utah (0)
11  NaN Hawaii (0)  Nevada (0)  Vermont (0)
12  NaN Idaho (0)   New Hampshire (0)   Virginia (1)
13  NaN Illinois (2)    New Jersey (7)  Washington (0)
14  NaN Indiana (0) New Mexico (0)  Washington, D.C. (3)
15  NaN Iowa (2)    New York (36)   West Virginia (0)
16  NaN Kansas (0)  North Carolina (1)  Wisconsin (0)
17  NaN Kentucky (2)    North Dakota (0)    Wyoming (0)
18  Additional Countries / Territories  Additional Countries / Territories  Additional Countries / Territories  Additional Countries / Territories
19  NaN Canada (1)  Germany (1) Unknown (3)
20  NaN England (5) Ireland (6) NaN
```

As you can see the data is in a list and very unstructured.  I want to make the data into two columns.  One with the header 'location' that houses the names of the states and countries and one named 'number' that houses the number within the ().  I want to remove duplicate values and NaN values but I believe I can do this if given proper direction on the rest.

I am lost as how to start.

Thank you!

Code used so far :

```
url = "http://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/birthplace.php?y=1876"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table')[6] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = df[0]
```

Comment: The code I used so far for this is :

Comment: url = "http://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/birthplace.php?y=1876"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table')[6] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df

Comment: Do not put codes in comments. You can click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56962260/edit) below your question and update it with the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make do with `str.extract` and `dropna()` followed by `drop_duplicates`:

```
pattern = '(?P<Country>[\w\s\.\,]*)\s+\((?P<value>\d+)\)'
(df.stack()
 .str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
 .dropna()
 .drop_duplicates()
)
```

Gives (only head):

```
            Country value
0  0   United States   105
1  1         Alabama     0
   2       Louisiana     2
   3            Ohio     4
2  1          Alaska     0
   2           Maine     0
   3        Oklahoma     0
3  1         Arizona     0
   2        Maryland     2
   3          Oregon     0
4  1        Arkansas     0
   2   Massachusetts     9
   3    Pennsylvania    28
5  1      California     0
```

For details on the regex pattern, paste the value of `pattern` [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Quang, thank you for your response.  When I try the code you mentioned I get a Attribute Error because the df is contained in a list.  So, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: Ah, it’s a list. You tagged pandas, so I assumed that it’s a DataFrame. Maybe replace `df` with `df[0]`?

Comment: that works! but only for the first value.  United States 105

Comment: @kdbaseball8 replace the space in the pattern with `\s+`. See update.